# sqlalchemy server_side_cursors mode can not repetitive execution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

When I create a engine by sqlalchemy.create_engine(uri, server_side_cursors=True), I can't reuse this engine with server mode,like this：

```
def test_mysql_search():
    uri = Const.mysql_URI
    engine = sqla.create_engine(uri, server_side_cursors=True)


    sql = "select 1 from z_voucher"
    df_g = pd.read_sql(sql, engine, chunksize=1)
    df = next(df_g)
    print(df)
    df = next(df_g)
    print(df)
    print('--------------------------------------------')
    sql2 = 'select * from AUDIT_BALANCE'
    df2 = pd.read_sql(sql2, engine, chunksize=1)
    df = next(df2)
    print(df)
    df = next(df2)
    print(df)
```

When I execute alone cut-off line above or below ,it can be fine. However, when I execute all, it can not reuse server mode. Should I close server side cursor, but I do not how to close it. 
My database is Mysql and my driver is pymysql.